# How to use Jasper Reports with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, jasper-reports, single-page-application

I googled for using JasperReports with AngularJS is possible or not, but I couldn't find any exact solution about that.

Let me explain our current situation and after that I will explain what I want to do.

We are using Spring for our application backend and JasperReports for generating reports on the server side. We have Pdf, Excel and HTML options for generating reports, all types of reports generated by JasperReports.

Now, we are developing a new application using AngularJS for front-end and again Spring for developing JSON based Rest services. Front-end and backend codes are running in different servers, we are using tokens for authentication.

My question, is it possible to generate reports with JasperReports and show to user in Pdf, Excel and HTML to users? If not, is there any solution to show reports to users in these formats with or without pagination?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you get the answer to this?

Comment: No, I didn't get an answer. We decided to go in another way.

Comment: What other way did you go?

Comment: In that time, we created report on server side and give a link to user to download. Now, we decided to develop restful services to generate report and visualise on client side with some plugins.

Comment: Oh nice, we also have a similar issue, I am thinking of going with server side with jasper reports. Which client side plugins did you use

Comment: If you want to show just pdf, html etc without any interactions you can do on server side and give a link or send an email about report to related user. this is not best i know but solution :)